# Use list comprehension to create a list of tuples for two different conditionals

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list-comprehension

Is there a way to use list comprehension to create a list of tuples with two different conditions.

I am interacting through a Pandas DF and I want to return an entire row in tuple if it matches either condition. The first is if the DF has nan values in any column.
The other is if a column in the DF called `ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME` doesn't match the regex pattern for the date column. The date column is supposed to have an output that looks like this:  `2005242132`. 10 number digits. So if the df returns something like 2004dg, it should be picked up as an error and the row should be added to my list of tuples

**My sad pathetic attempt:**

```
[tuple(x) for x in odfscsv_df[odfscsv_df.isna().any(1)].values or x in odfscdate_re.search(str(odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME'])) ]
```

Full Function that contains the two seperate list of tuples:

```py
def process_csv_formatting(csv):
    odfscsv_df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None,names=['ODFS_LOG_FILENAME', 'ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME', 'LOT', 'TESTER', 'WAFER_SCRIBE'])
    odfscsv_df['CSV_FILENAME'] = csv.name
    odfscdate_re = re.compile(r"\d{10}")
    #print(odfscsv_df)
    #odfscsv_df = odfscsv_df.replace('', np.nan)
    errortup = [(odfsname, "Bad_ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME= " + str(cdatetime), csv.name) for odfsname,cdatetime in zip(odfscsv_df['ODFS_LOG_FILENAME'], odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME']) if not odfscdate_re.search(str(cdatetime))]
    emptypdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ODFS_LOG_FILENAME', 'ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME', 'LOT', 'TESTER', 'WAFER_SCRIBE'])
 
    print([tuple(x) for x in odfscsv_df[odfscsv_df.isna().any(1)].values])

    [tuple(x) for x in odfscsv_df[odfscsv_df.isna().any(1)].values or x in odfscdate_re.search(str(odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME'])) ]
    #print(odfscsv_df[(odfscsv_df[column_name].notnull()) & (odfscsv_df[column_name] != u'')].index)
    for index, row in odfscsv_df.iterrows():
        #print((row['WAFER_SCRIBE']))
        print((row['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME']))
    #errortup = [x for x in odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME']]
    if len(errortup) != 0:
        #print(errortup)  #put this in log file statement somehow
        #print(errortup[0][2])
        return emptypdf
    else:

        return odfscsv_df
```

Sample CSV Data. The commas delienate the cells:

```
2005091432_943SK1J.00J.SK1J-23.FPD.FMGN520.Jx6D36ny5EO53qAtX4.log,,W943SK10,MGN520,0Z0RK072TCD2
2005230137_014SF1J.00J.SF1J-23.WCPC.FMGN520.XlwHcgyP5eFCpZm5cf.log,,W014SF10,MGN520,DM4MU129SEC1
2005240909_001914J.E0J.914J-15.WRO3PC.FMGN520.nZKn7OvjGKw1i4pxiu.log,,K001914E,MGN520,DM3FZ226SEE3
2005242132_001914J.E0J.914J-15.WRO4PC.FMGN520.V8dcLhEgygRj2rP2Df.log,2005242132,K001914E,MGN520,DM3FZ226SEE3
2005251037_001914J.E0J.914J-15.WRO4PC.FMGN520.dyixmQ5r4SvbDFkivY.log,2005251037,K001914E,MGN520,DM3FZ226SEE3
2005251215_949949J.E0J.949J-21.WRO2PP.FMGN520.yp1i4e7a7D1ighkdB7.log,2005251215,K949949E,MGN520,DG2KV122SEF6
2005251231_949949J.E0J.949J-25.WRO2PP.FMGN520.oLQGhc2whAlhC3dSuR.log,2005251231,K949949E,MGN520,DG2KV333SEF3
2005260105_001914J.E0J.914J-15.WRO4PC.FMGN520.wOQMUOfZgkQK9iHJS5.log,2005260105,K001914E,MGN520,DM3FZ226SEE3
2006111130_950909J.00J.909J-22.FPC.FMGN520.UuqeGtw9xP6lLDUW9N.log,2006111130,K9509090,MGN520,DG7LW031SEE7
2006111612_950909J.00J.909J-22.FPC.FMGN520.hoDl3QSNPKhcs4oA2N.log,2006111612,K9509090,MGN520,DG7LW031SEE7
2006120638_006914J.E0J.914J-15.CZPC.FMGN520.qCgFUH2H21ieT641i9.log,2006120638,K006914E,MGN520,DM8KJ568SEC3
2006122226_006914J.E0J.914J-15.CZPC.FMGN520.nSHSp7klxjrQlVTcCu.log,2006122226,K006914E,MGN520,DM8KJ568SEC3
2006130919_006914J.E0J.914J-15.CZPC.FMGN520.Zd6DrMUsCjuEVBFwvn.log,2006130919,K006914E,MGN520,DM8KJ568SEC3
2006140457_007911J.E0J.911J-25.RDR2PC.FMGN520.QPX9r59TnXObXyfibv.log,2006140457,K007911E,MGN520,DN4AU351SED1
2006141722_007911J.E0J.911J-25.WCPC.FMGN520.dNQLkvQlPTplEjJspB.log,2006141722,K007911E,MGN520,DN4AU351SED1
2006160332_007911J.E0J.911J-25.WCPC.FMGN520.DQiH82Ze9fCoaLVbDE.log,2006160332,K007911E,MGN520,DN4AU351SED1
2006170539_007911J.E0J.911J-25.WCPC.FMGN520.TjakhXkmhmlGhfLheo.log,2006170539,K007911E,MGN520,DN4AU351SED1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `dtype` parameter to import `'ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME'` as dtype string when you call `read_csv`

```
odfscsv_df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None,
                              names=['ODFS_LOG_FILENAME', 'ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME', 'LOT', 'TESTER', 'WAFER_SCRIBE'],
                              dtype={'ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME': str})

m1 = odfscsv_df.isna().any(1)
s = odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME']
m2 = ~s.astype(str).str.isnumeric()
m3 = s.astype(str).str.len().ne(10)

[tuple(x) for x in odfscsv_df[m1 | m2 | m3].values]
```

Comment: Actually its one condition. Everything is converted in to string for regex search. If you notice on the first comprehension I wrote for this isssue: 
[(odfsname, "Bad_ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME= " + str(cdatetime), csv.name) for odfsname,cdatetime in zip(odfscsv_df['ODFS_LOG_FILENAME'], odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME']) if not odfscdate_re.search(str(cdatetime))]
It only uses one condition. The cdatetime which is converted to string for the search. The regex then checks if it has 10 numeric digits. I don't need to sepreate it into multi conditions. first column is 'ODFS_LOG_FILENAME'

Comment: I guess I misunderstand. what is the 2nd condition to pick rows?

Comment: If the value in column 'ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME' is not a a num containing 10 digits. I purposefully cast the value to string when I feed it into regex to avoid all the wierd cases where Pandas turns my data into int and floats. Casting the value to string simplifies things

Comment: Btw, your s = statement gives me the error:
   raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: Try my updated answer. Add parameter `dtype` to `read_csv` and chain `astype`  as I shown in my updated answer.

Comment: I notice you didn't use regex. Would your code account for situations where the date time appears as 2200412d00 or 2020-14-12? Would it be faster to use regex? If so how would you modify it for regex?

Comment: it will include both to the list of tuples. It is definitely faster than regex searching

Comment: so m2 = ~s.astype(str).str.isnumeric() checks to see if it is not a number, and m3 = s.astype(str).str.len().ne(10) checks if it is a number but not equal to 10 and adds these seperate instances?

Comment: `m2` checks if strings contain any  non-digit character. `m3` checks any string has length NOT equal 10. If either `True`, add the row to list of tuples.

Comment: You're brilliant! It works. My question now is, is there a reason you chose the str methods as opposed to regex? Is it faster? better in what? @Andy L

Comment: `str` works on the whole series take advantage of vectorized operation, so is is usually faster than  regex from `re` module. I also prefer the readable of `str` accessor.

Comment: I see. Okay what if I need to use regex for a more intricate situation. Like where you need to do a more complex pattern match that cannot be addressed by your str methods (which seem to be ideal for a simple situation like this), how would one incorporate regex?

Comment: @edo101: in that case, you may need `str.extract`, `str.extracall`, or `str.findall`. More info: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html

Comment: I suggest you read docs on them to get familiar with them in case you prefer regex route.

Comment: According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/are-for-loops-in-pandas-really-bad-when-should-i-care string regex extractions are not advised. I tried to modify your code to this but it is not working: 
m2 = bool(odfscdate_re.search(str(s)))
[tuple(x) for x in odfscsv_df[m1 | ~bool(odfscdate_re.search(str(s)))].values]

How can i modify m2 to use my re.compile pattern: odfscdate_re = re.compile(r"\d{10}")
And actually return the right amount of not match occurences and only output those. The code as I modified it prints everything

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668139/how-to-use-regex-re-compile-match-or-findall-in-list-comprehension Sorry to do this to you but here is the follow up question. For clarity. It seems I've dragged you into an inception of Stack overflow issues.

Comment: I posted an answer to your new question.