# How to use regex re.compile Match() or findall() in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list-comprehension, python-re

I am trying to use regex in list comprehension without needing to use the pandas `extract()` functions.

I want to use regex because my code might need to change where I need to use more complex pattern matching. A kind user here suggested I use the `str` accessor functions but again it mainly works because the current pattern is simple enough.

As of now, I need to return pandas rows that either contain `nan` or whose values under `ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME` are not 10 string numbers i.e.: does not match the current format: `2020012514`. To this intent I tried to bypass the `str` method and use regex. However this doesn't do anything. It puts everything into my list of tuples even though I told it to only put values that only contain `nan` or where the `bool(regex.search())` is not true:

```
def process_csv_formatting(csv):
odfscsv_df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None,names=['ODFS_LOG_FILENAME', 'ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME', 'LOT', 'TESTER', 'WAFER_SCRIBE'], dtype={'ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME': str})
odfscsv_df['CSV_FILENAME'] = csv.name
odfscdate_re = re.compile(r"\d{10}")
errortup = [(odfsname, "Bad_ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME= " + str(cdatetime), csv.name) for odfsname,cdatetime in zip(odfscsv_df['ODFS_LOG_FILENAME'], odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME']) if not odfscdate_re.search(str(cdatetime))]
emptypdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ODFS_LOG_FILENAME', 'ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME', 'LOT', 'TESTER', 'WAFER_SCRIBE'])

#print([tuple(x) for x in odfscsv_df[odfscsv_df.isna().any(1) | odfscdate_re.search(str(odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME'])) ].values])
m1 = odfscsv_df.isna().any(1)

m1 = odfscsv_df.isna().any(1)
s = odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME']
m2 = ~s.astype(str).str.isnumeric()
m2 = bool(odfscdate_re.search(str(s)))
m4 = not m2
print(m4)
m3 = s.astype(str).str.len().ne(10)

#print([tuple(x) for x in odfscsv_df[m1 | m2 | m3].values])
print([tuple(x) for x in odfscsv_df[m1 | ~bool(odfscdate_re.search(str(s)))].values])

if len(errortup) != 0:
    #print(errortup)  #put this in log file statement somehow
    #print(errortup[0][2])
    return emptypdf
else:

    return odfscsv_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `re` module. You need to use it with `map`. For 10-digit strings, use this pattern `r"^\d{10}$"`

```
import re

odfscdate_re = re.compile(r"^\d{10}$")

m1 = odfscsv_df.isna().any(1)
m2 = odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME'].map(lambda x: 
                                                 odfscdate_re.search(str(x)) == None)
[tuple(x) for x in odfscsv_df[m1 | m2].values]
```

**Note**: depend on your requirement, I think you may also use `match` instead of `search`.

Comment: Wow thanks, what would I do without you Andy? Thank you so much. One thing, regex doesn't have a method called match. I only see search, findall, split and sub

Comment: @edo101: It's nice of you to say :). On `re.match`, python `re` module has `re.match` as  `re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html. Search inside that page you will see `re.match`

Comment: Lol I see that now. maybe I shouldn't ues W3Schools as gospel for leaning python. They didn't mention match. Well now I need to look at what .map() does cause I have never used it before. Why didn't my original way work: [tuple(x) for x in odfscsv_df[m1 | ~bool(odfscdate_re.search(str(s)))].values]

Comment: `re.search` checks on individual string. In your code, you pass `s` which is the whole series, so it doesn't work. Pandas `map` passes each value of `odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME']` to `lambda` function. So `x` in lambda is each string of `odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME']`. Therefore, `re.search` works correctly. On `Not Found`, re.search returns `None`, so we check the return of `re.search` against `None` to get the correct boolean mask

Comment: ohhh its a pandas method. AH didnt know that. was scratching my head googling. Thanks again Andy. if i ever run into you in person, I am buying you a big fat meal

Comment: You wouldnt happen to be in San Jose or Portland? If so, I'm serious about the meal lol. I appreciate the help through the chain of questions I've asked in the past hours and you graciously replying to follow up questions

Comment: Well um if you have time, could you look at another issue for me :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62682176/if-statement-condition-met-but-does-not-execute-python