# If Statement Condition Met but Does Not Execute (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

HI I have a list of windows path objects which I am running an if statement on. Background: I have several csv files. My code checks these csv files. If csv file is good, the script moves the file to a dir called "archive". If there is an error its moved to "error", if its empty it goes to "empty".

So I have a file that's been moved to archive. I copied this file back over to base dir for the script to process it. **However the if statement that is supposed to catch this duplicate doesn't execute and instead the script tries to move the file to the archive dir. When this happens, becaue I am using the Path.rename() method to move my files, I get the following error:
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\Users\sys_nsgprobeingestio\Documents\dozie\odfs\odfshistory\06_17_2020_FMGN520.csv' -> 'C:\Users\sys_nsgprobeingestio\Documents\dozie\odfs\odfshistory\archive\06_17_2020_FMGN520.csv'**

These are the functions involved. Anyone know why this is happening?:

```
def make_dict_of_csvprocessing_dirs():
    dir_dict = process_dirconfig_file(dirconfig_file)
    # print(dir_dict)
    dictofpdir_flist = {} #dictionary of lists of files in different processing dirs
    csvbase_file_dir = dir_dict["base_dir"]
    csvhistory_Phandler = Path(csvbase_file_dir)
    csvbase_path_list = [file for file in csvhistory_Phandler.glob("*.*")]
    dictofpdir_flist["csvbase_path_list"] = csvbase_path_list

    archive_dir = dir_dict["archive_dir"]
    archive_Phandler = Path(archive_dir)
    archivefiles_path_set = {file for file in archive_Phandler.rglob("*.*")}
    dictofpdir_flist["archivefiles_path_set"] = archivefiles_path_set
```

The function where error occurs:

```
def odf_history_from_csv_to_dbtable(db_instance):
    odfsdict = db_instance['odfs_tester_history']
    #table_row = {}
    totalresult_list = []

    dir_dict, dictofpdir_flist = make_dict_of_csvprocessing_dirs()
    print(dir_dict)
    csvbase_path_list = dictofpdir_flist["csvbase_path_list"]
    archivefiles_path_set = dictofpdir_flist["archivefiles_path_set"]

    for csv in csvbase_path_list:  # is there a faster way to compare the list of files in archive and history?
        if csv in archivefiles_path_set:
            print(csv.name + " is in archive folder already")
        else:
            csvhistoryfilelist_to_dbtable(csv, db_instance)
            df_tuple = process_csv_formatting(csv)
            df_cnum, odfscsv_df = df_tuple
            if df_cnum == 1:
                trg_path = Path(dir_dict['empty_dir'])
                csv.rename(trg_path.joinpath(csv.name))

    return totalresult_list
```

**When I debug Pycharm gives me the following values: Notice how the ticks for the directory listing are reversed. I wonder if this is the issue?:**

```
archivefiles_path_set={WindowsPath('C:/Users/sys_nsgprobeingestio/Documents/dozie/odfs/odfshistory/archive/06_17_2020_FMGN520.csv')}

csv = {WindowsPath}C:\Users\sys_nsgprobeingestio\Documents\dozie\odfs\odfshistory\06_17_2020_FMGN520.csv

csvbase_path_list = 
[WindowsPath('C:/Users/sys_nsgprobeingestio/Documents/dozie/odfs/odfshistory/06_17_2020_FMGN520.csv')]
```

Comment: If I reduce it, then people will tell me they need to see the whole code to understand @MisterMiyagi

Comment: Looks like the code of interest is 
` if csv in archivefiles_path_set:
            print(csv.name + " is in archive folder already")`

edo, can you print `csv` and `archivefiles_path_set` ?

I suspect you are expecting that `archivefiles_path_set` lists the directory contents, when in reality its just a string referencing the directory, but I cant really tell.

Also, while I sympathize with the too much/ too little code, this is certainly too much code. I dont think `make_dict_of_csvprocessing_dirs` is necessary to include untile someone asks about it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have edited it to be shorter. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @VincentBuscarello check my my edit. I added the values i get from Pycharm debug. The print statments you're looking for. Thanks again

Comment: @VincentBuscarello: That function is necessary (since it's where the values come from), but it's equally important to show what it ends up populating; we don't know what their folder structure looks like.

Comment: The folder structure is shown in the debug results section of my original post. That fucntion returns a tuple. one is the dictionary containing my processing dirs, the other tuple value is a dictionary of the list of windows path objects of each processing directory @ShadowRanger

Comment: @VincentBuscarello did you see the "print" statements you're asking for?

Comment: What library are you using to make those `WindowsPath` objects? I suspect you need to run a method to get the directory contents, not just the path.

Comment: @VincentBuscarello I am using "from pathlib import Path"

Answer (score 1):

Propbably fastest way to get which files to copy (if you are the only process accessing both dirs):

```
from os import listdir 

basedir = r"c:/temp/csvs"
archdir = os.path.join(basedir,"temp")

def what_to_copy(frm_dir, to_dir):
    return set(os.listdir(frm_dir)).difference(os.listdir(to_dir))

copy_names = what_to_copy(basedir, archdir)
print(copy_names) # you need to prepend the dirs when copying, use os.path.join
```

It seems your code is quite complex (lots of storing stuff in dicts to transfer to get it out again) for that little of a task. This is how it could work:

```
import os

# boiler plate code to create files and make some of them already "archived"
names = [ f"file_{i}.csv" for i in range(10,60)]
basedir = r"c:/temp/csvs"
archdir = os.path.join(basedir,"temp")

os.makedirs(basedir, exist_ok = True)
os.makedirs(archdir, exist_ok = True)

def create_files():
    for idx, fn in enumerate(names):
        # create all files in basedir
        with open(os.path.join(basedir,fn),"w") as f:
            f.write(" ")
        # every 3rd file goes into archdir as well
        if idx%3 == 0:
            with open(os.path.join(archdir,fn),"w") as f:
                f.write(" ")


create_files()
```

Function to "copy" a file if not yet exists:

```
def copy_from_to_if_not_exists(frm,to):
    """'frm' full path to file, 'to' directory to copy to"""
    # norm paths so they compare equally regardless of C:/temp or C:\\temp
    frm = os.path.normpath(frm)
    to =  os.path.normpath(to)

    fn  = os.path.basename(frm)
    dir = os.path.dirname(frm)

    if dir != to:
        if fn in os.listdir(to):
            print(fn, " -> already exists!")
        else:
            # you would copy the file instead ...
            print(fn, " -> could be copied")

# print whats in the basedir as well as the archivedir (os.walk descends subdirs)
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(basedir):
    print(root + ":", files, sep="\n")

for file in os.listdir(basedir):
    copy_from_to_if_not_exists(os.path.join(basedir,file),archdir)
```

If the read cache optimization of your harddrive is not good enough for you, you can cache the result of `os.listdir(to)` but its probably fine as is.

Output:

```
c:/temp/csvs:
['file_10.csv','file_11.csv','file_12.csv','file_13.csv','file_14.csv','file_15.csv',
 'file_16.csv','file_17.csv','file_18.csv','file_19.csv','file_20.csv','file_21.csv',
 'file_22.csv','file_23.csv','file_24.csv','file_25.csv','file_26.csv','file_27.csv',
 'file_28.csv','file_29.csv','file_30.csv','file_31.csv','file_32.csv','file_33.csv',
 'file_34.csv','file_35.csv','file_36.csv','file_37.csv','file_38.csv','file_39.csv', 
 'file_40.csv','file_41.csv','file_42.csv','file_43.csv','file_44.csv','file_45.csv',
 'file_46.csv','file_47.csv','file_48.csv','file_49.csv','file_50.csv','file_51.csv', 
 'file_52.csv','file_53.csv','file_54.csv','file_55.csv','file_56.csv','file_57.csv',
 'file_58.csv','file_59.csv']

c:/temp/csvs\temp:
['file_10.csv','file_13.csv','file_16.csv','file_19.csv','file_22.csv','file_25.csv', 
 'file_28.csv','file_31.csv','file_34.csv','file_37.csv','file_40.csv','file_43.csv',
 'file_46.csv','file_49.csv','file_52.csv','file_55.csv','file_58.csv']

file_10.csv  -> already exists!
file_11.csv  -> could be copied
file_12.csv  -> could be copied
file_13.csv  -> already exists!
file_14.csv  -> could be copied
file_15.csv  -> could be copied
file_16.csv  -> already exists!
file_17.csv  -> could be copied
file_18.csv  -> could be copied
[...snipp...]
file_55.csv  -> already exists!
file_56.csv  -> could be copied
file_57.csv  -> could be copied
file_58.csv  -> already exists!
file_59.csv  -> could be copied
```

See [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) for ways to cache results of functions - and consider putting the `os.listdir(archdir)` into a function that caches the result if IO reading gets to be a bottleneck (measure first, then optimize)

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for the effort and time. What do you mean my code is too complicated? Also what is this read cache optimization you speak of?

Comment: @edo  your harddisk has a cache, this code above reads the contents of the archive dir every time again - you could cache that if you fear that your harddrive cache does not allow a fast enought performance).  To simply get all the names you need to transfer right now - see edit at top - if reads the current dir with csvs once, reads the archived once once, gets the set difference and returns you all file names you need to copy from the csv-dir to your archive dir.